# Django, Ajax, csrftoken. Please tell me what is the problem

Tags: jquery, json, django, ajax, django-forms

UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
warnings.warn(

On HTML templates everything worked. After switching to AJAX, this error appeared
Tried these tips, did not help: [How can I send a CSRF token in a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485435/how-can-i-send-a-csrf-token-in-a-form). https://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/csrf.html.
addnew.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'table:addnew' %}" class="js-product-add-form">  
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title modalLabel">Добавить запись</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> 
            
                {% for field in form %}
                <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                  <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                  {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
                  {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Добавить" />
                    </div> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

views.py

```
def index(request):  
    snj = ScheduleNotJob.objects.all()  
    form = SNJ()   
    return render(request,"index.html",{'snj': snj, 'form':form})  


def save_product_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            SNJ = ScheduleNotJob.objects.all()
            data['html_product_list'] = render_to_string('table.html', {
                'snj': SNJ
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


def addnew(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SNJ(request.POST)
    else:
        form = SNJ()
    return save_product_form(request, form, 'addnew.html')  


def edit(request, id):
    elem = ScheduleNotJob.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SNJ(request.POST, instance=elem)  
    else:  
        form = SNJ(instance=elem)
    return save_product_form(request, form, 'edit.html')


def destroy(request, id):  
    snj = ScheduleNotJob.objects.get(id=id)  
    snj.delete()  
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('table:index'))
```

addnew.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var loadForm = function () { 
      var btn = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url: btn.attr("data-url"),
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
          $("#modal-product .modal-content").html("");
          $("#modal-product").modal("show");
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#modal-product .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        },
      
      });
    };
   

    var saveForm = function () {
      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: form.attr("method"),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.form_is_valid) {
            $("#bootstrapdatatable tbody").html(data.html_product_list);
            $("#modal-product").modal("hide");
            table.draw();
          }
          else {
            $("#modal-product .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    };

     // Add product
     $(".addSpan").on("click", loadForm);
     $("#modal-product").on("submit", ".js-product-update-form", saveForm);


    // Update product
    $("#bootstrapdatatable").on("click", ".editSpan", loadForm);
    $("#modal-product").on("submit", ".js-product-add-form", saveForm);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error as I mentioned in the comment, you can include the CSRF token in your AJAX request headers as follows

```
var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(); // get the CSRF 
token value from the form
$.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken); // include the CSRF token in the request headers
}
```

});

and also you need to modify your view, you need to replace the render_to_string to render then only we can render the template with the CSRF token context processor

the new view will be like follows

```
def save_product_form(request, form, template_name):
data = dict()
if request.method == 'POST':  
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        SNJ = ScheduleNotJob.objects.all()
        data['html_product_list'] = render_to_string('table.html', {
            'snj': SNJ
        })
    else:
        data['form_is_valid'] = False
context = {'form': form}
data['html_form'] = render(request,template_name, context)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

sorry for the late response I saw your message now. Try this and give me an upvote if it works for you if you have any issue just comment I'll try to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Your html page is  rendered without `RequestContext` so:

```
return render_to_response('yourpage.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

add this render to your views.py where you render the html page.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question how to apply this to my example? @sunderam-dubey

Comment: @kekai The answer is not given by me, I only edited it, you can say this to Noel S Jacob.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question how to apply this to my example? @noel-s-jacob please

Comment: there is no stupid question, if you don't understand you should ask,
In you example I don't know which is the html file you're rendering or I can't find the view which you're using for this html. But I figured a way to solve this. The error you're facing here is the CSRF token is not being passed to the server in your AJAX request

Comment: please try the last answer if you still struggling with the issue